# Converting an mp3 file to wav with ffmeg produces different size files depending on whether we use streaming

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg` to convert an `mp3` file to `wav`.  Depending on whether I use streaming mode, I get different size files.  In other words, the following generates different sized files:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 in.wav
ffmpeg -i - in.wav < in.mp3
```

What is `ffmpeg` doing differently in the two scenarios? Is one version inherently "better" than the other?

Comment: Share full logs. What is the difference in sizes?

Comment: Drors-MacBook-Pro:Downloads drormaydan$ ls -l in.mp3
-rw-r--r--@ 1 drormaydan  staff  9113 Jul 17 14:19 in.mp3
Drors-MacBook-Pro:Downloads drormaydan$ ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel error -i - in.wav < in.mp3
Drors-MacBook-Pro:Downloads drormaydan$ ffmpeg -nostats -loglevel error -i in.mp3 in2.wav
Drors-MacBook-Pro:Downloads drormaydan$ ls -l in.wav in2.wav
-rw-r--r--  1 drormaydan  staff  92502 Jul 17 14:27 in.wav
-rw-r--r--  1 drormaydan  staff  88354 Jul 17 14:27 in2.wav

Comment: My guess is that it may be skipping/replacing some container/codec metadata in the second form with generic metadata due to it receiving an unspecified input at the moment of execution, and then assigning a bare-minimum decoder which might not be the fully-flagged one that it would use otherwise. Adding a `-v verbose` may shed some light as to what ffmpeg is doing internally with both. As for which is better, the first one should supposedly be the better way to do things since it's the standard way to use ffmpeg and presumably is the one with more failsafes and optimizations coded into it.